Loading a new scene additively automatically loads inactive scenes
I am trying to load a new scene while maintaining an inactive scene inactive. I have three scenes. The "Main" scene, the "Options" scene and the "Heavy" scene. The game starts on the "Main" scene and the "Heavy" scene is loaded async and remains inactive like this:
SceneOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("Heavy", LoadSceneMode.Additive); 

SceneOperation.allowSceneActivation = false;

Then I load the new "Options" scene additive, like this:
SceneManager.LoadScene("Options", LoadSceneMode.Additive);

When doing this, the "Heavy" scene suddenly becomes active even though allowSceneActivation is set to false. I have tried changing the "Heavy" scene loading to single, but it doesn't fix the issue:
SceneOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("Heavy", LoadSceneMode.Single); 

SceneOperation.allowSceneActivation = false;


If I'm not wrong, what you're trying to do is pre-load multiple scenes and activate them on demand. There's a thread discussing that, and it says it can't be done. Check it here

This is obviously quite frustrating as in my opinion it is useful in some cases. I will have to find a workaround like leaving the scene loaded but with the root-object disabled. I thank you greatly for clarifying it.
